# sql subquery with count error

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, subquery

I have the following query

```
select   Obj.regcode,count(*) 
FROM     dbo.Objecten Obj          
INNER JOIN dbo.Dossiers Dos ON obj.objectnr=Dos.objectnr  
WHERE Dos.plan_gereed between '2014-01-01' and '2014-02-01'  
group by obj.regcode having count(*) > 1
```

works fine, it adds up and shows only the ones that have multiple regcode's.

now i want to split them again up, so i can view which dossiernr's are combined with the regcode. ( i need them to group first before i can determine which regcodes are used multiple times in the defined period)

so i thought my query would be like this:

```
SELECT   obj.regcode, Dos.dossiernr  
FROM     dbo.objecten obj, 
         dbo.Dossiers Dos  
WHERE    obj.regcode IN ( select   Obj.regcode,count(*) 
                          FROM     dbo.Objecten Obj          
                           INNER JOIN  dbo.Dossiers Dos ON obj.objectnr=Dos.objectnr  
                          WHERE Dos.plan_gereed between '2014-01-01' and '2014-02-01'  
                          group by obj.regcode 
                          having count(*) > 1 )  
AND      obj.objectnr=Dos.objectnr
```

but this one gives the following error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

anyone can help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just remove count(*) from the IN select check

```
SELECT obj.regcode, Dos.dossiernr FROM dbo.objecten obj, dbo.Dossiers Dos WHERE obj.regcode IN ( select Obj.regcode FROM dbo.Objecten Obj INNER JOIN dbo.Dossiers Dos ON obj.objectnr=Dos.objectnr WHERE
Dos.plan_gereed between '2014-01-01' and '2014-02-01' group by obj.regcode having count(*) > 1 ) AND obj.objectnr=Dos.objectnr
```